# Best sql type for a Credit card password

Tags: sql, passwords, sqldatatypes

I'm working on a credit card project that interacts with people's money and so I need to store a password. This password should not contain any character but numbers [0-9] and it should be a 4-digits always.

I don't know what sql data type to use for this password.

Here are some situations I have in mind:
**A.** If I chose `int` I should check the password to be between 1000 and 9999
**B.** if I chose `Char(4)` then I should check the password to be only numbers (and not characters)
**C.** if I chose Decimal(4,0) then I'm sure that it's below 10000 but I still need to check it for being greater than 999

**What** do you suggest for such a password and **why**?

Comment: Are you going to ask people to enter pin codes and store them? )

Comment: @NPE this is a real project so I'm concerned about it and I'm not playing around.

Comment: @beherenow Yes actually people can change their password.

Comment: @NPE Every one is not as knowledgeable as you are, you can make fun of others, you can help them. I'd be happy if you could help me gain some experience and learn something. I think we are here to learn and teach, aren't we? I'm learning.

Comment: I don't think you have to worry, because I doubt any financial institution would allow to do what you are proposing. The fact that you are posting here means your team is woefully under skilled to withstand the hacking that's definitely coming you way when people learn you are storing PINs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the pin code as Char(4). If you choose 'int' you will have problem by some pin codes like '0042' because it will store without zero.
If you chose Char(4) you can validate the the pin code by this method Char.IsNumber(ch).

Comment: Not all pins are 4 digits. My bank allow up to 8.

Comment: @Bohemian you are right, PINs are not always the same, but as I've mentioned in the question in my case it is 4-digit.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I would say that you shouldn't store the password at all, but a [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function#Password_verification) of it.  However, with only 10,000 possible passwords, there's not really much point — no amount of [key stretching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_stretching) is going to stop an attacker from brute forcing a four-digit password if your database is compromised.

However, what you *could* do, at least, is to encrypt the password (combined with a random [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29), so that two identical passwords don't map to the same ciphertext) with a key stored in some secure manner.  Ideally, you should store the key in a [hardware security module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module) from which it cannot be extracted, and have the HSM take care of encrypting and verifying the passwords.

(The HSM should not allow decrypting a password, either; the only allowed queries should be "encrypt this password with a random salt" and "check if this password matches this encrypted string".  If possible, the module should also feature some built-in rate limiting, so that even if an attacker manages to take over the server connected to the HSM, they still at least have to spend some time to crack all the passwords.  Ideally, them module should also report the rate at which it is being queried, and the fraction of successful queries, to another, physically separate monitoring server.)

Anyway, if you're dealing with credit card data, it's likely that there are other fields in your database that also should be stored securely.  Generally, there are quite detailed industry regulations and/or laws governing all this stuff — have you already checked which of them apply to you and what they say?

Comment: Actually we've not checked any rules/laws for what you say because it is some kind of private project and it is not a complete banking system but some parts of it. But I check logins, if 5 failed logins happen the card will be locked in DB and the user should come to an agency will their Idenetification.  
And I like the Encryption and Hashing suggestions, Why didn't I count it before?